# How can I get user_id in separated place?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel& make dictionary and connect the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary.
Excel is
[image: excel]

user_id is in F1,so I really cannot understand how to make dictionary.
Now views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()

book2 = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel2.xlsx')
sheet2 = book2.sheet_by_index(0)
headers = sheet2.row_values(0)

large_item = None
data_dict = {}
for row_index in range(sheet2.nrows):
    rows2 = sheet2.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows2[1] or large_item

    # Create dict with headers and row values
    row_data = {}
    for idx_col, value in enumerate(rows2):
        header_value = headers[idx_col]
        # Avoid to add empty column. A column in your example
        if header_value:
            row_data[headers[idx_col]] = value
            # Add row_data to your data_dict with
    data_dict[row_index] = row_data
    for row_number, row_data in data_dict.items():
        user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id = data['user_id']).exists()
        if user1:
            user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict)
            user1.save()
```

My codes only can catch data in same place(in this case B4~E4),so I cannot understand how to write to achieve my goal.How should I write it?
Ideal dictionary is

```
{"user_id":1, "name":"Blear","nationality":"America","domitory":"A","group":1}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what your dictionary should look like after parsing that file.

Comment: @MartinEvans I updated my question.If u know something,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your spreadsheet appears to only have one entry? If this is the case, you do not need to iterate over the rows, but instead just extract the locations you need, for example:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

cells = [
    ('user_id', 0, 5),
    ('name', 3, 1),
    ('nationality', 3, 2),
    ('domitory', 3, 3),
    ('group', 3, 4)]

user1 = {key:sheet.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}

print user1
```

Giving you:

```
{'nationality': u'America', 'user_id': 1.0, 'name': u'Blear', 'group': 1.0, 'domitory': u'A'}
```

This uses a Python dictionary comprehension to build the `user1` dictionary based on `cells`.

Comment: thx,ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but IndexError: list index out of range error happens.

Comment: Traceback says 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 112, in <module>
    user1 = {key:sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 112, in <dictcomp>
    user1 = {key:sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}
  File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 415, in cell_value
    return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if you know something ,please help me.